# Ruby on Rails error with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have an app that works on Heroku, but on my local machine gives me this error after i try to sign in:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise/registrationsController#create
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using Rails 3.0.3, Ruby 1.9.2 and latest Devise version.

Comment: Did you modify any of the default Devise controllers/views?

Comment: +1 I'm experiencing a similar problem (but usually on sign–in and only every now and then) and yes, I have modified controllers and views. Any ideas?

Comment: @Raidfive: i'm joining a project which is half done. And i couldnt get hold of the actual developer at the moment for some reason. The app works fine on Heroku, but when i cloned the app from heroku, a couple of pages work fine for me but not all of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading some other posts online, have you tried clearing your cookies and changing your session key? Seems to be a common suggestion but people are having mixed results with the solution it sounds like.

Comment: Thanks raidfive, i've tried clearing my session cookies. that did'nt worked. However, i'm interested in knowing how to change the session key? Any directions?

Comment: You can find your session store key in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`